# python: list access with hash values

Tags: python

I want acces python lists with a hash:

```
hashtable = []
hashtable.append(132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a: 'foo' )
```

But on execution it doesn`t accept the hash as an index:

```
python3 ./hdd/search.py
  File "./hdd/search.py", line 10
hashtable.append(132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a: 'foo' )
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a possibility to use the list with a hash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you mean to use a dictionary? `hashtable = {}; hashtable[132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a] = 'foo'`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'd suggest making that an answer. OP could possibly want a list of dicts, but that doesn't seem feasible here with what's been provided.

Comment: yes, but after syntax correction it doesn`t work...

Comment: "I want acces python lists with a hash" well, you can't do that. Why don't you just use the hashmap data-structure, the `dict`?

Comment: What doesn't work? How are you accessing it? With what @hiroprotagonist suggested, you'd access the value by looking up the key (as opposed to an index number): `print(hashtable['132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a'])`

Comment: @stevieb that is a syntax error. `132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a` is not a valid python name

Comment: I just corrected my comment, @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: correction on my first comment: you need to prepend your integer in hex with `0x` in order to make it a valid python identifier: `hashtable[0x132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a] = 'foo'` (or put it in quotes as @stevieb suggests above).

Comment: now it works with :
`hashtable = {'132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a':'foo'}`

and :
`def visitfile(file):
    md5 = md5Checksum(file)
    print(hashtable[md5])`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Make it an answer.

Comment: @stevieb ok, done. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the datatype that seems to fit your need seems to be the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict). you can use it this way:

```
hashtable = {}
hashtable[0x132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a] = 'foo'
# or directly:
# hashtable = {0x132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a: 'foo'}
```

and then access the values like this:

```
value = hashtable[0x132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a]
```

note hat `132328df455b0028f13bf0abee51a63a` is not a valid python integer; you need to prefix hexadecimal numbers with `0x`.